# How to get back hosts file after accidental deletion

Tags: linux, unix, ubuntu-14.04

I made a mistake and accidentally deleted hosts file from my system and cannot figure out how to get back my hosts (/etc/) file, when i do

`sudo service apache2 restart`

it's showing
sudo: unable to resolve host SystemName.

I am using ubunt 14.04 Lts
Please help me out, i am just beginner.

Edit:
I did by sudo vi hosts and put

```
   127.0.0.1       localhost
   ::1             localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
   fe00::0         ip6-localnet
   ff00::0         ip6-mcastprefix
   ff02::1         ip6-allnodes
   ff02::2         ip6-allrouters
```

Comment: I’m voting to migrate to [su], but you might get a better response on [ubuntu.se].

Comment: I got help here to Don't worry admins, if it off topic you must not have these tags here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no simple way to recover a deleted file (unless you have a backup).
If your host-name is **SystemName**, then recreate it with a line like:
**127.0.0.1       SystemName**

Comment: please check my Edit... but no avail

Comment: Please include the contents of /etc/hostname

Comment: /etc/hostname contains 'SystemName' only!!

Comment: Perfect, so please change 127.0.0.1 localhost to the line the answer says: 127.0.0.1 SystemName

Comment: I change 'SystemName' to '127.0.0.1   localhost' and run the command sudo service apache2 restart but it shows same error.

Comment: In your /etc/hostname leave SystemName, in your /etc/hosts you must have 127.0.0.1 SystemName

Comment: I had to add   127.0.1.1   SystemName too , now resolved thanks for your try... I am accepting it as answer for your effort. Thanks buddy.